# SQL: Replace ID in String

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, replace

Here's the scenario --

I have two tables Names & Sentences:

```
Names                   Sentences
ID | Names              ID | Description                   
1  | Fox                1  | The <1> jumped over the <2>
2  | Narwhal            2  | The <2> sailed to the <3>
3  | Moon
```

I need to return all the Descriptions from the Sentences table with the ID replaced with the corresponding Name from the Names table, e.g.

'The Fox jumped over the Narwhal', 'The Narwhal sailed to the Moon'.

I'm stumped at where to begin with this, in theory it appears like a simple problem but my knowledge of manipulating Strings is limited.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Btw, this doesn't sound like a problem you can handle with SQL Queries. It would be better to handle it in code.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve that in a dynamic way with ANSI SQL, but take a look at the `REPLACE` command, might help you.

Comment: I was hoping that there might be a solution such as - SELECT REPLACE(SENTENCES.DESCRIPTION, [SQL query to identify id/s in <>], NAMES.NAMES). Or to that effect.  *EDIT* Ortang got in just before me, thanks I'll have to investigate whether it's possible.

Comment: @ephron - It's doable but not pretty.  If there was only ONE set of replaces it would be pretty straightforward.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should at least get you started.  This is messy to do because you have multiple-level replacements, and no `JOIN` key in the data itself.

This uses two `CROSS JOIN`s and a bunch of string functions, so it will be **very inefficient.**  This will never run quickly on a large data set.

```
DECLARE @names table (id int, names varchar(100))
DECLARE @sent table (id int, descr varchar(1000))

INSERT INTO @names
VALUES
(1, 'Fox'),
(2, 'Narwhal'),
(3, 'Moon')

INSERT INTO @sent 
VALUES
(1, 'The <1> jumped over the <2>.'),
(2, 'The <2> sailed to the <3>.')

SELECT DISTINCT Filtered
FROM (SELECT Replace(REPLACE(descr, '<' + CAST(n.id as varchar) + '>', n.names), '<' + CAST(n2.id as varchar) + '>', n2.names) Filtered
      FROM @sent s, @names n, @names n2) x
WHERE Filtered NOT LIKE '%<%'
```

Comment: Thanks JNK, fortunately it's for a one-off use at work and isn't going to be executed on a large set of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function and then select using that function.  But, as JNK said, I'm not sure how to do it with two replaces.  My question and reply ([SQL Server change font in html string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376995/sql-server-change-font-in-html-string)) gives an example of replacing one string with another using a function.  You're essentially replacing '<1>' with a selection set and then '<2>' with a selection set for each of the first set.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that might be faster at the expense of burning yr retinas:

```
SELECT
LEFT(Description, CHARINDEX('<', Description)-1)
+ Name1
+ SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX('>', Description) + 1, CHARINDEX('<', Description, CHARINDEX('<', Description) + 1) - CHARINDEX('>', Description) - 1)
+ Name2
FROM Sentences
JOIN Names AS Name1 ON Name1.ID = CAST(SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX('<', Description) + 1, 1) AS INT)
JOIN Names AS Name2 ON Name2.ID = CAST(SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX('<', Description, CHARINDEX('<', Description) + 1) + 1, 1) AS INT)
```